# How to run a module without importing it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a es6 module which extends the RegExp object. I'm using the `Object.defineProperties` to do it:

```
Object.defineProperties(RegExp.prototoype, {
  ...
});
```

I'm not returning anything in this file, because I don't need it since RegExp is global in `Node.js`, but in the same way I need to import something to run the code that will extend the RegExp.prototype. Do you see the problem?

What is the work around in this case? Just return a `export default {}`? Isn't this a bad thing? I was thinking about returning the RegExp and overwriting in the import:

```
import RegExp from '@scope/regexp';
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why not `class CustomRegExp extends RegExp` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
import '@scope/regex';
```

This will just run the code in the module, without importing anything.